# Pop-up window or modal box?

Tags: javascript, popup, modal-dialog

I'm designing a mission-critical web application and I was wondering if it is best to have users enter in data via browser pop-up windows or javascript modal boxes?

The absolutely critical aspect is that data must save correctly through HTML forms.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm designing a mission-critical web application and I was wondering if it is best to have users enter in data via browser pop-up windows or javascript modal boxes?

I would tend towards self-made, modal boxes for a number of reasons: Input elements can be styled, can be made more convenient, and `prompt()` dialogs tend to get eaten by IE's popup blocker.

However, the method of input you choose is not essential: The correct encoding of the page containing the input form, the database connection and the database tables storing the data is what's really important.